# Incorrect time in envelope summary

Tags: docusignapi

On the development server I have an account configured to use the EST/EDT timezone for the API calls.
It seems that with this configuration, the API calls return a date with an incorrect time.

For example, I have created an envelope at 12:46 GMT but the API to get the envelope summary is returning the following date:

**2015-06-10T15:46:25.8165848Z**

If I am not wrong, the time is incorrect because Z is the timezone for UTC and so I was expecting 12:46:25.8165848Z.

Setting the timezone for the API calls to pacific time, the date returned is correct:

**2015-06-10T12:46:25.8165848Z**

Am I using the API correctly?

For example the API call:

```
GET https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/917973/envelopes/b7c31971-53e1-417e-b132-e27514befdcf/audit_events HTTP/1.1
```

returns an incorrect time for the audit events when the user is configured with a timezone that is not "pacific time".

Comment: Are you using REST or SOAP? And which calls are you doing to create envelope and retrieve the data above?

Comment: IIRC I repro'd this some time ago. There is a patch in the works for this - that is as much as I can advertise.

Comment: I am using a java api that based on REST.

Comment: I am using the java API docusign-restclient to call the DocuSign REST services.
The library calls for example the following url to get the audit trails:

GET https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/917973/envelopes/b7c31971-53e1-417e-b132-e27514befdcf/audit_events HTTP/1.1

This call returns incorrect time when the user is configured with a timezone that is not "pacific time".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DocuSign support confirmed what @luis-scott wrote. For now it is not known when the bug will be fixed.